# Rails/Webpack: How can I ensure imported component can see jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I'm trying to incorporate a Bootstrap theme into my app.

I have added the required components to my web pack:

```js
import Rails from 'rails-ujs';
window.Rails = Rails;
Rails.start();

import Turbolinks from 'turbolinks';
Turbolinks.start();

import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;

// Front Bootstrap template
import "../vendor/front-v2.8.0/assets/scss/theme.scss"
// Front JS Global Compulsory
import "../vendor/front-v2.8.0/assets/vendor/jquery-migrate/dist/jquery-migrate.min.js"
import "../vendor/front-v2.8.0/assets/vendor/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
import "../vendor/front-v2.8.0/assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"
// JS Front
import "../vendor/front-v2.8.0/assets/js/hs.core.js"
import "../vendor/front-v2.8.0/assets/js/components/hs.header.js"
```

However, when I load the page, I get an error in the JS console:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery  jquery-migrate.min.js
```

So I see that despite having imported jQuery about jquery-migrate, jquery-migrate does not know about it. I assume I'm not importing my assets correctly. Is there a way I can make jquery available to jquery-migrate without actually changing jquery-migrate's code?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of jQuery, you must make it available with `$` and `jQuery`. Open the `config/webpack/environment.js` file and add the following lines just above `module.exports = environment`.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
}))
```

Source: https://medium.com/michelada-io/from-the-asset-pipeline-to-webpack-ce5a4bc323a9